# Is it bad to convert int to String only to access its digits?

Tags: string, int

I'm getting into a habit of converting `int` numbers to `String` to access its digits.
For example:

```
int number = 2899;
String number_str = String.valueOf(number);
StringBuffer reversedNumber = new StringBuffer();

for(int i = number_str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    reversedNumber.append(Character.getNumericValue(number_str.charAt(i)));
}
```

I believe there's another more common way to access the digits, namely, using a series of `mod 10` and `div 10`. I understand `mod 10` will give the `n-th` digit while `div 10` will give `1 to (n-1)th` digit of any given number with length `n`. But, I feel converting to `String` and accessing its characters is more convenient.

One of the examples when I converted `int` to `String` was on this question I asked on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74441/stepping-number-solution-optimization

I basically wanted to check if a number was a stepping number. For example:

```
input: 8343545
output: 8343545 is a stepping number
```

**Explanation:** 8343545 can be written as 8,343,545. **Def:** *A number is called a stepping number if every adjacent digits, except those separated by commas, differ by 1.*

There are many other `int` problems I have done previously and used `String` conversion to access digits of a number. I just want to know is it bad to do this? Could you explain why is it bad and `mod 10` or `div 10` is preferred?

Comment: In general. But if the answer is different for different languages, I'm currently using Java

Comment: If it's convenient for you, it isn't bad. If you're only pulling out the last digit or something like that, you may want to compare the performance of the two approaches via benchmarking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it bad?

**No it is not, generally speaking**. I actually prefer it:

- Very easily understandable by people. Compare it with division/mod10 - not too many beginners will understand that. You code for people.
- It's very easy to implement. Far less chance to write buggy code.

That said, **ALL** the good libraries use div10/mod10 method. First of all, library **consumers** don't really know the details, nor do they particularly care. Secondly, it performs much better, in performance wise.

There is very good chance that your use case does not require hyper-super performance. If it does - you know exactly what has to be done.

Comment: I don't know about performance. My gut feeling tells me that `String.valueOf(number)` should do the divs and the mods to produce the string representation, so everything else (e. g. going over every character to fetch it) would be excess computation.

Comment: @LordHenryWotton; not sure I follow you. `String.valueOf(number)` does use div/mod to produce the string representation.

Comment: Chris, what I mean is if `String.valueOf(number)` is using the traditional approach (divs and mods) why not just use divs and mods directly?

Comment: @LordHenryWotton: the div/mod10 approach is harder to read, takes time to debug, is less intuitive for many people. It's matter of choice, I've been on both spectrums, but I prefer the string approach, unless working with performance sensitive code.

Comment: I don't dismiss your point about readability and maintenance of code, I only question performance. Using `String.valueOf(number)` or similar will add a second pass to the number. If you are doing this millions or billions of times, this be hurtful.

Comment: @LordHenryWotton: There is no doubt about what you're saying. The performance between these two "solutions" will be massive if benchmarked million/billion times. As always, prefer the solution which is more readable & easier to change, unless you have reason not to. Obviously, if I would be doing code for a case where method will be called million/billion times, and performance was necessary, I wouldn't go with string manipulation. My real life experience shows that most of uses cases I've encountered, are not run million or billion times.